# MOPS Media Recipe Protocol - Well Defined

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, microbiology

I am trying to find a clear protocol for making MOPS media. However, when looking online, I am finding that this media is loosely defined and I can not find a good protocol. (I have been looking for a couple of hours now)

In addition, there seems to be something called 'MOPS buffer'. What is the difference between the two?

Additionally, if someone could direct me to a good protocol for this media I would appreciate it.

Comment: This seems to depend strongly on what you want to do with the bacteria.  What do you want to do with you bacteria? Mops is one of the buffer substances used in bioscientific reasearch. Dissolved in water and brought to the right pH it makes MOPS Buffer.

Comment: I am doing a metagenomic anaylsis on soil, thus there are probably multiple bacterial types. It is suppose to be used for a general culturing media.